# Overflow scrollbar not showing on 100% height div in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have recreated a CSS compatibility issue I have come across between Chrome and Firefox.

An "inner" DIV with 100% height inside a Table cell which is inside a "container" DIV of fixed height. I want the inner DIV to fill the cell and dynamically add text to it such that a scrollbar appears when it begins to overflow.

In the JSFiddle you can see the code in both Chrome and Firefox. In Chrome it behaves as expected but in Firefox the scrollbar doesn't display and the inner DIV just keeps expending beyond the height of the container DIV.

[JSFiddle code to try in both Chrome and Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/jpudo5pc/9/)

HTML as follows:

```
<style>
#container {
  height:80px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:vertical;
}

#inner {
  height:100%;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

table{
  height:100%;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <div id="inner">
    Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <img src="https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/images/used-in-examples/video/qmlvideo/images/close.png" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

EDIT, further requirement: I forgot to mention that I have this setup inside a resizable DIV i.e. the Container DIV is able to resize it's height so that the table and Inner DIV resize accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried with "overflow-y:scroll"?

Comment: The first question you should ask is why is this in a table - this does not look like tabular data so I'm guessing that you should figure out another way to layout the page that is more semantically correct.  WIth that in mind, I would use display:flex for this

Answer (score 0):

```
    #inner {
      border: 2px solid red;
      height: 75px;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 300px;
    }
```

You can use this CSS. I think it may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a common mistake. Whenever an element is set to `height: 100%` or any other percentage, it relates to the `height` of its parent. So when using this, its important to define a `height` for the parent of your element:

To demonstrate the problem: Adding a class to the parent `<td class="fix">` and add some css fixes the problem:

```
.fix {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
}
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpudo5pc/7/)

Keep in mind that setting the `display` attribute of a table cell from `table-cell` to `block` is something you should avoid, as you are changing the elements roots. Consider a solution without using a `<table>` markup if you have got the possibilities.

Comment: your fix pushes the red box outside the container (which breaks the chrome version)